# How to use VBA to Save As with a dynamic file type

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to write code that will automate updating inventory spreadsheets for different vendors. I have run into a problem when it comes to saving the files as the vendors require different file types when uploading the inventory. So what I am needing is some code that will dynamically change the save as file type depending on the vendor.

What I have so far is a multi-select file dialogue which the user utilizes to select the spreadsheets they want to update. The VBA I have so far loops these selected templates which are opened, updated via formulas in the spreadsheet, and then saved  in a different folder and named with the vendor name and the current date.

Here is the problem section of code I am working with:

```
CustomerWB.SaveAs Filename:="S:\Online Inventory Reports\" _
                & Left(CustomerWB.Name, 6) _
                & "\" _
                & Left(CustomerWB.Name, 6) _
                & " " _
                & Format(Now(), "MM.DD.YY") _
                & WorksheetFunction.Index(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("B:B"),WorksheetFunction.Match(Left(CustomerWB.Name, 6),ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A:A"),0)), _
                FileFormat:=WorksheetFunction.Index(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("C:C"),WorksheetFunction.Match(Left(CustomerWB.Name, 6),ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A:A"),0))
```

I have debugged each piece of the code and it works up until I hit the `Index(Match()` sections.

The formulas are looking into a table which has the vendor IDs next to the required file type and type code. When run in the immediate window, these formulas produce the desired result. But when they are run in this code, an error is returned: `Run-time error '1004': Method 'SaveAs' of Object '_Workbook' failed` So it seemed like VBA didn't like the fact I was mixing in worksheet functions when trying to save the file.

So I moved the `Index(Match())` sections into the spreadsheet and had the VBA populate a cell with the vendor name. Then assigned variables to the values of the cells which now returned the file type and type code. The new code looks like this:

```
CustomerWB.SaveAs Filename:="S:\Online Inventory Reports\" _
                & Left(CustomerWB.Name, 6) _
                & "\" _
                & Left(CustomerWB.Name, 6) _
                & " " _
                & Format(Now(), "MM.DD.YY") _
                & FileType, _
                FileFormat:=TypeCode
```

But I get the same error. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what are the file types you are trying to save as?

Comment: What are the potential values for `TypeCode` which are stored on the worksheet?  If you're taking this approach you must use the numeric values for the various fileTypes - you cannot use (eg) the string "xlWorkbookDefault" but instead should have 51 (the numeric value)

Comment: The files I am attempting to save as are .csv, .xlsx, and .xls with type codes 6, 51, and 56 respectively

Comment: Maybe try `Debug.Print` ing the constructed filename to make sure there are no problems there

Comment: I changed the bottom two lines to comments and ran the code through the MM.DD.YY part, and that saved the file in the desired directory. So it works up until that point. 

And I ran the index match sections and the variable sections in the immediate window, and they returned the correct values. 

There just seems to be a problem when joining them together.

Comment: Maybe make sure `TypeCode` is numeric and not coming in as a string

Comment: ```TypeCode``` is declared as an integer

Comment: assume FileType is the extension of the file?  If so then you are missing a period between the date format and the extension.

Comment: The Index(Match()) returns the file extension as *.xslx, *.csv, or *.xls. Would I need an additional period on top of the one that is returned?

Comment: Try hard-coding the FileFormat for a know extension - does that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a simple error. I had the asterisk included in the file extension being returned (ex. *.xlsx). Upon removing the asterisk from the file extensions in the table, the code ran fine.